# Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser name: ${peerName}, url:grpcs://${peerAddress}, connected:false, connectAttempted:true

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-ingress

I have hyperledger fabric network with:

- TLS CA
- Org CA
- Org Intermediate CA
- Peer
- Orderer
- Chaincodes

My network deployed in k8s cluster. I have not root privileges in this cluster. There are specific root cert and key from my organization for this cluster. That's why I have same error from all pods:

```
${time} UTC 056d ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 9.509µs with error EOF server=${component} remoteaddress=${my_org_k8s_cluster_host}:${port}
```

But this error didn't affect on my network deployment. I try to do request to my network via ingresses from my node.js app and I receive this error:

```
${time} - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: ${peerName}, url:grpcs://${peerAddress}:${peerPort}, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
${time} - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server ${peerName} url:grpcs://${peerAddress}:${peerPort} timeout:10000
${time} - info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser ${peerName} due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: ${peerName}, url:grpcs://${peerAddress}:${peerPort}, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
    at checkState (/path/to/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:74:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/path/to/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:500:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  connectFailed: true
```

I tried to generate certificates for ingress from TLS CA, included all possible peer and order hosts there, created a new secret for k8s and put them there. Now, when I try to create a channel block from fabric tools by command:

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=${org}MSP
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=${peer_ingress_addr}:${ingress_port}
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/path/to/admin/msp;
peer channel create -c ${channel_name} -f /path/to/channel.tx -o "${orderer_ingress_addr}:${ingress_port}" --outputBlock /path/to/${channel_name}.block --tls --cafile /path/to/tls-root-cert/tls-ca-cert.pem;
```

I got errors:

```
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = Bad Gateway: HTTP status code 502; transport: received the unexpected content-type "text/html"
```

in orderer logs:

```
​${time} UTC 00ec ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 9.012µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=${host}:${port}
```

from node js I have same error: Failed to connect...